# How Are Functions Evaluated When Passed As Arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, sequence, execution

In Javascript, functions are 'first class citizens'. However, I am a bit confused about how they are evaluated when passed as arguments to a function.

```
const childFunction = () => (
...
);

const parentFunction = ( childFunction ) =>(
...
);
```

I am wondering what is the sequence of the flow of the code. So would it be something like this:

'parentFunction' is executed. Argument 'childFunction' is identified as an argument, 'childFunction' is executed. Once result received from 'childFunction', then body of 'parentFunction' is executed?

Thanks,

Comment: `childFunction` will only be executed if and when the `parentFunction` executes it. It doesn't get executed implicitly.

Comment: @squint thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childFunction` is not executed by just being passed as an argument. The function that takes `childFunction` has to call it using `childFunction()` or `childFunction.apply/call`

```
const childFunction = () => (
...
);

const parentFunction = ( childFunction ) =>(
   // childFunction doesn't get called/executed until this line is reached
   childFunction();
   // Or something like
   childFunction.call(this, 1,2,3);
...
);
```